# SQLite transaction vs sqlBatch

Tags: javascript, angular, sqlite, cordova-plugins, ionic4

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DemoTable (name, score)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?1,?2)', ['Alice', 101]);
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?1,?2)', ['Betty', 202]);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('Transaction ERROR: ' + error.message);
  }, function() {
    console.log('Populated database OK');
  });
```

Can you tell me why should I choose `sqlBatch` instead of `transaction`?

```
db.sqlBatch([
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DemoTable (name, score)',
    [ 'INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?,?)', ['Alice', 101] ],
    [ 'INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?,?)', ['Betty', 202] ],
  ], function() {
    console.log('Populated database OK');
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('SQL batch ERROR: ' + error.message);
  });
```

What benefits do I have? It seems both support the rollback feature.

Doc: https://github.com/xpbrew/cordova-sqlite-storage#using-draft-standard-transaction-api

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Comment: @CristopherRosales No. I have decided to use 1st option i.e. `transaction` due to it gives great performance out of the box. link: https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-971aff98eef2